# Why is fastcall used for replacing thiscall functions in memory instead of cdecl?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, c++, c

Assume I were to be reversing some game which processes all of it's movement client side and have determined some function to be of the type:

```
bool __thiscall Player::CanJump(Player *this)
```

that I have determined to be a member of the Player object's vtable. Now lets assume I wanted to edit that object's vtable to point to my own dll injected implementation so that I could jump whenever I wanted. I could declare it as

```
bool __fastcall CanJumpReplacement(Player *player) {
    return true;
}
```

and replace the Player's vtable entry with a pointer to this function. This works as expected, but *why should I use the fastcall convention here*? Fastcall is used almost exclusively for this purpose from what I can tell, but I was reading through the calling conventions and cdecl seems to be a much closer match to thiscall than fastcall. Both calling conventions succeeded in replacing the function.

Comment: Doesn't the x64 Calling convention replace _thiscall anyway with _fastcall ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170
[x64 calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is a bit confusing.

Both `__fastcall` and `__thiscall` share that they use `ecx` as the first storage point. So either you implicitly say the class pointer will be in `ecx` (`__thiscall`) or you say the function is not a member function but has one argument - which also gets passed in `ecx` when using `__fastcall` so the class pointer still ends up in the right register.

Also, both calling conventions use callee cleanup so no problem here, too.

However, this only works for no-argument functions. If your function had an argument, it would end up in `edx` for `__fastcall`, but on the stack for `__thiscall` and therefore not work anymore.

Comment: Ok, so basically fastcall is preferable for functions with no arguments, otherwise you would have to use cdecl/stdcall depending on context and read ecx manually to get the this pointer.

Comment: That is a different question really. For my last project that required C++ member function hooking, I wrote 2 small wrapper functions defined as `__declspec(naked) __stdcall` which had inline assembly code that turned the this pointer from `ecx` to a standard stack argument on entry, and on exit took the `this` pointer from the stack and moved it into `ecx` again.

Comment: Doesn't the x64 Calling convention replace _thiscall anyway with _fastcall ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170
[x64 calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170)